# express cookies do not work in the frontend section

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, mern

I'm working on a mern stack project with next.js framework. I hold the jwt token with a cookie and perform its verification directly over the backend. I use a useEffect on the index page to logout when the cookie expires. If there is no cookie, it needs to logout. When I was in the development phase (on localhost) everything was working flawlessly. But when I take the project live, it doesn't work. I am using vercel for the frontend server and aws ec2 for the backend server.

**index.js - logout useEffect**

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(getCookie('acces_token'));
        if (getCookie("access_token") === undefined) {
            logOut(dispatch);
        }
    }, [])
```

**Express google login controller**

```
const googleAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (user) {
      const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: "5d" });
      res.cookie("access_token", token, {
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + (30 * 24 * 3600000))
      })
      res.status(200).json(user._doc)
    } else {
      const newUser = new User({
        ...req.body
      })
      const savedUser = await newUser.save();
      const token = jwt.sign({ id: savedUser._id }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: "5d" });
      res.cookie("access_token", token, {
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + (30 * 24 * 3600000))
      })
      res.status(200).json(savedUser._doc)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

The main problem is that I can provide cookie access through localhost. I can also see cookie when site is live. The problem is that when he tries to read, he just throws undefined. Although there is data inside.

**Like this**
[image]

Comment: Please post the code for `getCookie`

Comment: getCookie coming from 'cookies-next' but I think problem is not here because firstly I was using document.cookie. It works for localhost. When I took it alive, I changed it when I saw it wasn't working. But still not working. @JustinTaddei

Comment: Are you serving your live site over https?

Comment: Yes, when I served https, I realized that there was an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem later with cookie domain. In the Domain section write like this ".yourdomain.com" on when set cookies, it will accept all domain-linked cookies.